# How to scroll from left right to left on a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jlabel

I have a JLabel on which I added an RSS Feed. But how can I slide the text from right to left, because the feed is too long and I want to read the whole feed.

```
final JLabel news = new JLabel("Loading";
news.setText(readRSSFeed("http://yourfeed.com");
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is it possible to autostart it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you should be adding your label to a container like this `add(news)`. So if you replace it with `add(new JScrollPane(news))` it will show scrolls if text overflow to visible area.